# Script to install rdp certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I have 300+ server 2012r2 severs that we need to reinstall the ssl cert for. We can manually go ahead and install it but for 300+ servers that is going to get a bit mundane. There has to be a script or powershell commands that will allow me to automate this. I found a script and modified it but it doesnt appear to either replace or add the cert to rdp, what am I doing wrong?

```
$CertificatePassword ="certpassword"
$CertificateImport ="location to cert"
$RDCB = "$env:COMPUTERNAME"+".domainname.com"
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
#Import the RemoteDesktop module
Import-Module RemoteDesktop
#Certificate Password
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $CertificatePassword -
AsPlainText -Force  
#Configure RDPublishing Certificate for RDS
set-RDCertificate -Role RDPublishing 
-ImportPath $CertificateImport 
-Password $Password 
-ConnectionBroker $RDCB -Force 
#Configure First RDWebAccess Certificate for RDS
set-RDCertificate -Role RDWebAccess 
-ImportPath $CertificateImport 
-Password $Password 
-ConnectionBroker $RDCB -Force 
#Configure RDRedirector Certificate for RDS
set-RDCertificate -Role RDRedirector 
-ImportPath $CertificateImport 
-Password $Password 
-ConnectionBroker $RDCB -force 
#Configure First RDGateway Certificate for RDS
set-RDCertificate -Role RDGateway 
-ImportPath $CertificateImport 
-Password $Password 
-ConnectionBroker $RDCB -force`
```

[image]

Comment: Post your manual steps, and we can try to mimic that using powershell

Comment: Does it need to be installed to a specific store?

Comment: I go to the edit deployment properties go to certs and then I can change what cert is being used for the 4 options there.

Comment: just adding it to the certificate store doesnt do anything. I have looked at doing that through gpo but that wont replace it in rdp settings.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the Remote Desktop Listener certificate? If so, check out [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remotely-install-RDP-8b9a82d3) script.

Comment: Im trying to change the cert that rdp is using.

Comment: Does your script literally look like that? Because that looks like unfinished commands `set-RDCertificate -Role RDGateway` which will fail then `-ImportPath $CertificateImport ` as a separate command which will fail, etc.

Comment: Im new to powershell scripting what should it look like?

Comment: `set-RDCertificate -Role RDWebAccess -ImportPath $CertificateImport -Password $Password -ConnectionBroker $RDCB -Force` should be on one line, no line breaks in the middle of the command parameters, for all the set-rdcertificate lines and the ConvertTo-SecureString line